# Laravel - File::deleteDirectory not working with cronjob

Tags: php, laravel, cron

This is my path:

`$path = '/home/vagrant/Code/myproject/public/uploads/tmp/819c6dc404fa716050cff6';`

I put the bellow code in controller and run it:
`File::deleteDirectory($path);`

It's OK. But when cronjob runs the directory is NOT deleted.

I try change the path to:

`$path = '/users/mac/Code/myproject/public/uploads/tmp/819c6dc404fa716050cff6';`

The directory is deleted when cronjob runs.

I don't understand !!!

Comment: Probably file permissions: a cron task is unlikely to be executing as the same user as the webserver

Answer (score 0):

Use a sudo in cron command (and add cron user with nopasswd flag to sudoers file)

See https://askubuntu.com/a/173932/282611 example/

Comment: So anybody can do `su cron` on an opened session and gain root access? Why not directly run cron as su by using `su - ; crontab -e`?